# What should I do so that custom fonts still work in the final assembly on computers where there are no such fonts?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project, Everything Works Well in Visual Studio and in bin Builds.
[image]
But when I create an independent build for Win x64 (dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release -o ./publish) and run the project on another computer where there are no such fonts, then everything turns into a mess of standardArial fonts.
[image]
What should I do so that custom fonts still work in the final assembly on computers where there are no such fonts?

**Update**:

[image]

**.csproj:

```
 <ItemGroup>    
     <Resource Include="Shayne.ttf">
  </ItemGroup>
```

ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <FontFamily x:Key="BuxtonSketch">C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\0127\FontDemo\Shayne.ttf</FontFamily>


<Style x:Key="CustomFont_Buxton" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Buxton Sketch">

    </Setter>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="FontDemo.App"
             ...
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Fonts.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()  { }
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            VictorianFonts.Load();
            new MainWindow().Show();
        }
    }
   
    public static class VictorianFonts
    {
        private static string fontFolder = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Fonts", "#");
        private static List<Afont> fonts = new List<Afont>
        {
            new Afont{ResName="Shayne", FontName="Shayne" },
        };


        public static void Load()
        {
            foreach (var fnt in fonts)
            {
                Application.Current.Resources.Remove(fnt.ResName);
                var ff = new FontFamily(fontFolder + fnt.FontName);
                Application.Current.Resources.Add(fnt.ResName, ff);
            }
        }

        private class Afont
        {
            public string ResName { get; set; }
            public string FontName { get; set; }
        } 
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <TextBlock x:Name="DownloadProgressText" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="{DynamicResource  BuxtonSketch}"
               FontSize="20" Foreground="White" Width="970" Margin="15,244,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="156">
        <Run Text="Text Custom Font Buxton"/><LineBreak/><Run/><LineBreak/>
        <Run Text="This article is among the articles of the presentative of the Ministry of Labor and Social Affairs”. "/>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Update2 :
[image]

Comment: You don't have a Fonts folder in your FontDemo.  Lose the Fonts from Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Fonts", "#");

Comment: Hi,@Andy.  I re-added .ttf to the folder. Still doesn't work.   Is there a specific description of the font in the code?     private static List<Afont> fonts = new List<Afont>
        {
            new Afont{ResName="Shayne", FontName="Shayne" },
        };

Comment: That's the other thing it could be. The fontname is quite often not the ttf name. If you install a font and take a look in font viewer you can see the name in blue. EG Amaltea is Amaltea WF.  This is why there are the two properties in my afont class.  Shayne.ttf could be  anything - say "Shayne is a great font designer" in fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have some real world apps do this.

You need to deliver your ttf files along with the game exe.

You can then load them as fontfamilies.

You need to use absolute addressing when loading such a font family. There is a bug in wpf which creates a memory leak if you use relative address.

I'll explain what I do in our game editors and you can then choose as much as you like of that.

I allow the user to switch fonts at run time. They can choose victorian or modern themes and hence fonts essentially.

I have a resource dictionary which I merge in app.xaml with keyed fontfamilies. This initially uses regular windows fonts for everything.

I have dynamicresource for each text usage.

The ttf fonts go in a fonts folder. I know what's in there so I can just work with a hard coded list of them.

The ttf files properties are set to content, copy if newer. When I compile they appear in my bin, in a fonts folder.

Before I show mainwindow I need to substitute my fonts for those out the ttf files. So in app.xaml.cs I have an Application_Startup method explicitly news up mainwindow.
Before I show it I call my fonts loading method.

The code looks like:

```
public static class VictorianFonts
{
    private static string fontFolder = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Fonts", "#");
    private static List<Afont> fonts = new List<Afont>
        {
            new Afont{ResName="XXX", FontName="XXX XX XXXX" },
            new Afont{ResName="YYY", FontName="YYY yy YYYY" }
        };


    public static void Load()
    {
        foreach (var fnt in fonts)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.Remove(fnt.ResName);
            var ff = new FontFamily(fontFolder + fnt.FontName);
            Application.Current.Resources.Add(fnt.ResName, ff);
        }
    }

    private record Afont
    {
          public string ResName { get; set; }
          public string FontName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That finds where the exe is running from, then looks for the fonts in a font folder within that.

I have a VictorianResources resource dictionary which will be merged in app.xaml.

```
 <FontFamily x:Key="XXXX">SegoeUI</FontFamily>
 <FontFamily x:Key="YYYY">Gabriola</FontFamily>
```

And I have some code which switches out to other resources when the user changes theme.

```
    public bool VictorianStyle
    {
        get { return victorianStyle; }
        set
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/UILib;component/Resources/VictorianStyle.xaml", UriKind.Absolute) };
                Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
                VictorianFonts.Load();
            }
            victorianStyle = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi,@Andy. Could you see the update part in my answer? I still don't show correctly